PowerCLI: How can I enable SSH on a vCenter Server Appliance?
Through the management interface served on port 5480 by default, you can enable SSH access to a vCenter Server Appliance. How can it be done programmatically using PowerCLI?

There are two ways to do it:

Connect to your VCSA via Connect-VIServer and enable SSH like this:
$body = Initialize-AccessSshSetRequestBody -Enabled $true
Invoke-SetAccessSsh -AccessSshSetRequestBody $body


Connect to your VCSA via Connect-CisServer and enable SSH like this:
$CisService = Get-CisService -Name 'com.vmware.appliance.access.ssh'
$CisService.set($true)



